# How to set variables from find+exec?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to write a bash script where I am trying to find if some location has empty files or not and send an email if found. I first thought about combining "find" and "mail" together, but if the location has multiple empty files, it would send multiple mails, which I do not want, so I thought of setting a flag variable to zero before find and setting it to 1 inside find if an empty file is found. This is what I tried:

```
FLAG=0
find $LOCATION -size 0 -type f -exec sh -c 'export FLAG=1' \;
echo $FLAG
```

but the problem is , even if the location has empty files, the flag value is not changing to 1. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

```
set -- "${LOCATION}/"*
while [ -s "$1" ] ; do shift ; done
[ -e "$1" ] && FLAG=1
```

The shell builtin `[ test ]` can be used with the `-s`ize operator. From `man test`:

> `-s FILE`
>
> > `FILE` exists and has a size greater than zero

That won't easily work for recursive searches though.

`find` will, but for a matter as simple as setting a boolean value, it really is not a good fit for this case. `ls` can do recursive searches just as fast, can easily be configured to provide file size as the first field for a listing and to list only one entry per line - guaranteed. If you want to set a shell variable's boolean value based on whether or not a recursive file-listing contains a 0-size file then `ls` is your best bet - `find` only complicates things. What you're interested in is file properties, not file locations. This is where `ls` shines, and `grep`ping its output is a breeze.

You can do it this easily:

```
ls -1aqRsp "$LOCATION" 2>&1 | grep -qv "^ *[^0]\|/"
FLAG=$(($?==0))
```

That will only set `FLAG` to `1` if a file - *hidden* `.dot` files included - exists in `$LOCATION` or in one of its child directories with a size of zero. Otherwise, `$FLAG` is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

`find` is forking a new child process when you do `-exec`.  No child process can alter it's parent's environment.

You might consider collecting the file names in question with `find` and then generating the email you want in a second pass:

```
find . -type f -size 0 -print >> /var/tmp/find.sz0
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, will it help if instead of exec, the output of find is piped into xargs ?

Comment: You would use `xargs` from a pipe if you wanted to process multiple arguments (here, files) as a bundle to reduce the number of processes spawned.  Terminating `find` with `{} +` produces the same effect.  Neither are needed to generate the list of files you want.

Answer (score 0):

That `export FLAG=1` is performed in the instance(s) of `sh` invoked by `find`. The environment of a process is never copied back to its parent. A shell process that only sets an environment variable and exits accomplishes nothing lasting.

If you want to test whether `find` matches any file, you can simply test if its output is empty. To avoid potentially generating a long list of files only to discard it once it's been proved to be non-empty, you can truncate the `find` output at the first opportunity. GNU find has a `-quit` predicate, and you can also easily tell it to display a single character. In the following snippet, `FLAG` ends up empty if there is no match:

```
FLAG=$(find "$LOCATION" -size 0 -type f -printf 1 -quit \;)
```

The following variant sets `FLAG` to 0 or 1:

```
FLAG=$(find "$LOCATION" -size 0 -type f -printf 1 -quit \;)
[ -n "$FLAG" ] || FLAG=0
```

If you want to stay portable, you can make `find` print matches and retain only the first line; `find` will die of a [SIGPIPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGPIPE) after `head` closes its side of the pipe.

```
if [ -n "$(find "$LOCATION" -size 0 -type f -print | head -n 1 \;)" ]; then
  FLAG=1
else
  FLAG=0
fi
```

If this was just a simplified example and you need to set more complex variables, there are several possible approaches. I'll just mention a couple of common ones.

Zsh has a lot of use cases of `find` built in thanks to [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers). The following snippet sets `files` to the list of files matched by `find $LOCATION -size 0 -type f`:

```
files=(**/*(.DL0))
```

Ksh and bash also have recursive globs if enabled with `set -o globstar` and `shopt -s globstar` respectively. However beware that with bash up to 4.2, `**` recurses into symbolic links to directories, which is usually not desirable. You can do further processing in the shell.

```
FIGNORE=         # include dot files in wildcard matches (the ksh way)
GLOBIGNORE=.:..  # include dot files in wildcard matches (the bash way)
for x in **/*; do
done
```

If none of the matching file names contain newlines, you can parse the output of `find` as a newline-delimited list.

```
find "$LOCATION" -size 0 -type f ! -name '*
*' -print | {
  while read -r empty_file; do
    …
  done
}
```